# Generic used in conjunction with Sort(Comparison<T>)

Tags: c#-4.0

Im wondering if its possible to reuse my overload of the Sort(Comparison) method to sort both labels and textboxes by tabIndex. Ive already tried and i couldnt get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
foreach(Control control in gbUserInputs.Controls)
        {
            if (control is Label)
            {
                inputLabels.Add((Label)control);
            }

            if (control is TextBox)
            {
                inputTxtboxes.Add((TextBox)control);
            }
        }
```

Sort method call(this doesnt work).

```
inputLabels.Sort(sortMyInputs<Label>);
```

Overload of sort method.

```
private static int sortMyInputs<T>(T entry1, T entry2)
    {
        return entry1.TabIndex.CompareTo(entry2.TabIndex);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be making a generic method:

```
private static int CompareLabels(Label entry1, Label entry2)
{
    return entry1.TabIndex.CompareTo(entry2.TabIndex);
}
```

The point of a generic delegate is to allow it to hold methods of different concrete types; not to allow it to hold methods that are themselves generic.

If you want to reuse your method, you can modify it to take `Control` (which both `TextBox` and `Label` inherit); you would still be able to pass it to `List<Label>.Sort` because of delegate covariance.

---

If you're using .Net < 4, which doesn't have delegate covariance, you can do it your way by adding a constraint to the method so that it knows what `T` can be:

```
private static int CompareLabels<T>(T entry1, T entry2) where T : Control
{
    return entry1.TabIndex.CompareTo(entry2.TabIndex);
}
```

---

You can also simply replace all of your code with one line of LINQ:

```
inputLabels = gbUserInputs.Controls.OfType<Label>()
                                   .OrderBy(c => c.TabIndex)
                                   .ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry for what is probably a stupid question, but where does the generic delegate come into this? I havent covered LINQ's yet but thanks for including that. Yes im using .net 4.0. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: @HansRudel: `Sort()` takes a `Comparison<T>`, which is a generic delegate.

Comment: I highly recommend that you learn LINQ; it makes this kind of code substantially shorter and much more readable.  (and is usually faster too)

Comment: yeah ok... D'oh. Its on my list of things to do but there are still a few of the basics that im not 100% upto speed with. Thanks very much for taking the time to answer my question, i really appreciate it!